# I have a problem with install Ubuntu (laptop HP)

Tags: system-installation, hp

I have a problem with install Ubuntu 13.10, 12.04 on the Laptop HP Pavilion dv6000.

I think that problem with vedeocard, Nvidia gforce 750M.

photo: 
[image]

Comment: resolved. Make nomodeset in LiveCD (F6)

Comment: Suggest you make that an Answer by posting it below, then click on the checkmark-in-circle at left to show it worked for you. Stack Exchange sites are designed to build a knowledge base so others can get help from what we do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose nomodeset option with LiveCD (F6).

Source and credit: comments from CoolDark above